# What is the type of child

Tags: typescript, react-native

What is the type of a `child`?

```
renderChildren(): void {
  const {children} = this.props;
  const childrenArray = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return this.renderChild(child);
  })
  ...
}

renderChild = (child: whatAmI): void => {
  ...
}
```

Digging in the code it looks like it is `ReactNode` but I did not find an official doc for `react-native` on this, and I would like to **know**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As covered in [the React Typescript cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#useful-react-prop-type-examples), the best type for children (and many other things) is `React.ReactNode`. It's very versatile, works with arrays and strings, etc.